# Create VSTS/TFS build task dynamic inputs

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

Regarding: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks

Is it possible to create a task that acts like the Get sources Workspace mappings, where I can have an [+ Add] button to add as many values as needed?

[image: here is an example]

I've been looking through documentation and sample blogs, but all examples I find have a pretty basic task.json.  And I haven't found another task to add that has this functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: The map workspaces isn't really a VSTS task, it's more of a custom UI that wraps around the `TF` tool. I haven't found any way to achieve this as of yet. To get around this, I have my VSTS task point to a JSON file which can be dynamic and the task works with it as necessary.

Comment: That is what I was assuming as well.  Was really hoping that wasn't the case, though, as it would be very handy for a number of tasks.

Comment: I agree. You can always suggest it in the user voice forum. https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be achieve. The "Add" option you see is not for build tasks just as virusstorm mentioned.

For build tasks, you can only specify a fixed number of inputs in the task.json. We are working on adding dictionary input which may help you with this kind of issues.

Refer to these links for details:

[Support complex input types](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/issues/48)

[Multiple task inputs](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/2980)

Comment: Eddie, that is the conclusion I have come to.  As your response has links pointing to the issue being discussed I will mark it as the answer.  Do you know the ETA for dictionary inputs?  The "it's coming" comments from those links were from over a year ago.

Comment: Do you mind taking a look at a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68096837/azure-pipeline-custom-task-with-an-unknown-number-of-inputs